# Why won't my function pass the correct value?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I have a zybooks section that has a challenge that is killing me.  The following only code i can change is the createlicenseNum function.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DogLicense{
   public:
      void   SetYear(int yearRegistered);
      void   CreateLicenseNum(int customID);
      int    GetLicenseNum() const;
   private:
      int    licenseYear;
      int    licenseNum;
};

void DogLicense::SetYear(int yearRegistered) {
   licenseYear = yearRegistered;
}

// FIXME: Write CreateLicenseNum()

void DogLicense::CreateLicenseNum(int customID) {
   int licenseNum;
   int licenseYear;
   licenseNum = 0;
   licenseNum = (100000 * customID) + licenseYear;

}


int DogLicense::GetLicenseNum() const {
   return licenseNum;
}

int main() {
   DogLicense dog1;

   dog1.SetYear(2014);
   dog1.CreateLicenseNum(777);
   cout << "Dog license: " << dog1.GetLicenseNum() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the output when GetLicenseNum() is ran, the output is 0.  I tried adding in a cout to the createlicenseNum function to see what licenseNum equals when its ran and I get a nonzero number, but it is not correct. I know the problem, I think, is with the passing of variables, but I am lost at how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
void DogLicense::CreateLicenseNum(int customID) {
    licenseNum = (100000 * customID) + licenseYear;

}
```

You are creating shadowed variables in your existing `CreateLicenseNum`. This means that `licenseNum` and `licenseYear` are locally scoped to `CreateLicenseNum`. The local `licenseNum` and `licenseYear` are not initialized to a specific value, so `licenseYear` can be anything.